# Calling a function inside Code.gs in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Basically, I have a javaScript.html file enclosed with a script tag  that is embedded to my Index.html using <'?!= include('javaScript'); ?> without the " ' " before the <.

What I am trying to do is call function globalVariables, located on my Code.gs, inside my javaScript.html but whenever I want to access isEditor's value, I always get an error of "Uncaught ReferenceError: globalVariables is not defined"

Code I want to access in Code.gs

```
function globalVariables(){ 
var varArray = {
 //Other items here                             
isEditor: true                                             
};
return varArray;
}
```

Code in my javaScript.html that needs to access globalVariables

```
  function createTable(dataArray) {
     
     google.script.run.globalVariables();

     var data = globalVariables().varArray[6].value;

     var isEditor = data;


 if(isEditor == true){
  //other code here
```

Comment: In this case, please use [`withSuccessHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)). You can see the sample scripts from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+withSuccessHandler).